# Get contents of a Safari windows in Applescript

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I would like to get the contents of a Safari 5.1 (Mac OS X) webpage and paste it into another application using Applescript.

I am relatively au fait with AppleScript, but not with JavaScript, having made the assumption that the answer lies with JavaScript.

I can use System Events to use key strokes to Select All and then Copy… which works fine, but I have two issues with this:

1. It's ugly, and surely there must be a way to programatically do this.
2. I can't undo the Select All that I did, which is even uglier?

Can anyone help?

Thanks, Nic.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

```
set the webpage_content to ""
tell application "Safari" to set the webpage_content to the text of document 1
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set the text of the front document to the webpage_content
end tell
```